# Finite Element - Plotting with stresses in triangle mesh

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, mesh

I'm making program where I need to plot some area which has been split up in many triangles. I have calculated strains in each node / each corner of the triangle. Now I need to plot the triangle with the strains.

Now I have three ways of plotting the triangles. But in one of them I fill each triangle with the average of it's corners strains. What I want to do is...
Put the strain on the corner and get a plot that looks like contour or contourf. - I don't really understand how they work.

Can anyone help me?

```
clear; clc;
TC = [ 1 2 3 ; 2 3 4 ] ;            % Triangles node Connection.
NC = [ 0,0 ; 0,1 ; 1,0 ; 1,1 ] ;    % Node Coordinates.
strain = [ 300 , 400 , 500 ; 400 , 500 , 600];  % Strains in each node.;

[ne,np] = size(TC);             % Just finding how many elements.

element =   zeros([3 2 ne]);    % Creating a matrix for each element.

% My first and second plot...

for i=1:ne
    no1 = TC(i,1); no2 = TC(i,2); no3 = TC(i,3);
    element(:,:,i) = [  NC(no1,1),NC(no1,2);
                        NC(no2,1),NC(no2,2);
                        NC(no3,1),NC(no3,2);];          % Defining each element for each loop.

         %    Node 1         Node 2         Node 3 
    xe = [element(1,1,i),element(2,1,i),element(3,1,i)];    % Defining coordinates to plot.
    ye = [element(1,2,i),element(2,2,i),element(3,2,i)];


    subplot(3,1,1)
    plot([xe, xe(1)],[ye, ye(1)])  % ATTEMPT ONE   % Only plotting the triangles. Using first value also last to close the triangle.
    xlim([-1 2]); ylim([-1 2])
    hold on

    subplot(3,1,2)
    fill(xe,ye,mean(strain(i,:)))  % ATTEMPT TWO   % Fill triangles with average strain.
    hold on
    xlim([-1 2]); ylim([-1 2])
end

% ATTEMPT 3
subplot(3,1,3)
TR = triangulation(TC,NC);
triplot(TR)
hold on
xlim([-1 2]); ylim([-1 2])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fill` function to get the shading that you desire. With a little bit of customization for your application I believe the following code will work, although some vectorization may be in order if the `for` loop slows your program too much.

```
X = zeros(3,size(TC,1));
Y = zeros(3,size(TC,1));
C = zeros(3,size(TC,1));

for i = 1:size(TC,1) % for all triangle connection definitions
    for j = 1:3      % for all nodes in a triangle
        X(j,i) = NC(TC(i,j),1)';    % format X points
        Y(j,i) = NC(TC(i,j),2)';    % format Y points
        C(:,i) = strain(i,:)';      % format color based on strain value
    end
end

fill(X,Y,C)
```

The result:

[image]

[You may want to check this documentation for further details on how X,Y and C are interpreted](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html)